# How to uninstall facebook's nuclide from atom?

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I have installed [facebook's nuclide](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide) to try it out for hvvm/hack development for atom via:

```
apm install nuclide-installer
```

After running and installing it, my atom became incredibly slow and hangs on startup, which is why I want to get it uninstalled.

Yet

```
$ apm remove nuclide
Uninstalling nuclide ✓
```

does not get rid of it. It still makes atom incredibly sluggish and starts up with the default page.

Comment: This is probably an issue you should open on the github page

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix You are correct, sometimes I treat stackoverflow as a hammer ... [The issue has been opened](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/266)

Comment: I've found the atom-community to be somewhat lacking via github, so this is probably a good place to start in general

Answer (score 4):

The Nuclide site has a page for uninstalling past versions of Nuclide: http://nuclide.io/docs/editor/uninstall/

You can uninstall all packages via `apm` by passing it the full list:

```
apm uninstall \
hyperclick \
nuclide-arcanist \
nuclide-blame \
nuclide-blame-provider-hg \
nuclide-blame-ui \
nuclide-buck-files \
nuclide-busy-signal \
nuclide-clang-atom \
nuclide-clipboard-path \
nuclide-code-format \
nuclide-code-highlight \
nuclide-debugger-atom \
nuclide-debugger-hhvm \
nuclide-debugger-lldb \
nuclide-diagnostics-store \
nuclide-diagnostics-ui \
nuclide-diff-view \
nuclide-file-tree \
nuclide-file-watcher \
nuclide-find-references \
nuclide-flow \
nuclide-format-js \
nuclide-fuzzy-filename-provider \
nuclide-hack \
nuclide-hack-symbol-provider \
nuclide-health \
nuclide-hg-repository \
nuclide-home \
nuclide-installer \
nuclide-language-hack \
nuclide-move-pane \
nuclide-objc \
nuclide-ocaml \
nuclide-open-filenames-provider \
nuclide-quick-open \
nuclide-react-native-inspector \
nuclide-recent-files-provider \
nuclide-recent-files-service \
nuclide-remote-projects \
nuclide-service-monitor \
nuclide-test-runner \
nuclide-toolbar \
nuclide-type-hint \
nuclide-url-hyperclick
```